# Backup manager shows an error when I connect my external HDD

Tags: mount, backup, ntfs

I have set Ubuntu to take a backup every day in my external (NTFS) hard drive. Usually I forget to connect it, I get a notification that the backup is being delayed, I connect my hard drive and the Backup Manager pops-up with an error:

"Backup Failed: An operation is already pending"

Is there anything I can do? I use Ubuntu 14.04.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is being tracked under [Bug #617012](https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+bug/617012). You may add your vote there to increase the relevancy for this bug to being fixed.